# App does not update through managed google play store

Tags: android, google-api, android-management-api, android-enterprise

I can't update the app through Android management API. Here is my policy:

```
{
    "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",      
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
      "minimumVersionCode": 10206,
       "delegatedScopes": ["ENABLE_SYSTEM_APP","PACKAGE_ACCESS"]

    }
  ],
  "stayOnPluggedModes": ["AC"],
   "screenCaptureDisabled": true,
   "installAppsDisabled": true,
   "dataRoamingDisabled": true,
   "adjustVolumeDisabled": true,
   "maximumTimeToLock": "0",
   "appAutoUpdatePolicy": "ALWAYS",
   "setupActions":[
     {
       "launchApp": {           
              "packageName": "XXXXXXXXX"          
       }
     }
   ],
   "systemUpdate": 
     {
        "type" : "AUTOMATIC"
     }


}
'''
```

I'm always getting a response on app update "Can't install the apps" the settings on this device don't allow you to install the apps. 
What do I need to do in order to have stable updates?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the property "installAppsDisabled" needs to be set to false in order to receive updates.